# Virtualbox having a plethora of problems

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox

I have had Ubuntu for about 2 months and for the last month I have been using [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) to run a few other operating systems inside of Ubuntu. For the past week I haven't really used Ubuntu as I have been working on dual booting Windows. Yesterday I booted into Ubuntu with the intention of using virtualbox. When I tried to boot into one of my OSs on there it gave me this:

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine.

The virtual machine has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: MachineWrap
Interface: IMachine {85cd948e-a71f-4289-281e-0ca7ad48cd89}

and
[(See picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tctti.png)

I have tried too many solutions to mention. 
More problems:

1. Virtualbox won't uninstall
2. Rebooting dosn't help
3. Trying to uninstall from Ubuntu software won't work
4. file:///var/lib/dpkg/lock is locked and i don't know how to open it
5. Virtualbox seems to be running a process that I can't kill
6. Every time I install something from command line it says at the end

   ```
   Errors were encountered while processing virtualbox-dkms
   ```

So basically what I need is for people to throw solutions at me and I can try them and tell you what the result is. Right now I just want to either fix virtualbox, or uninstall it and download it again.

Comment: How did you install vb in the first place, and where did you get it from?  What version are you trying to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news. I fixed the problem! I downloaded the install package from the virtualbox website and when I fired it up and it somehow overwrote or replaced the old one and now it is working fine. If you're having the problem I did download the package here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads.

Comment: Please click on the checkmark at left to show you accept the (your) answer, which changes the icon for the question to show folks here's a problem with a solution accepted by the person asking, which helps them a lot.